# node.js persistent store json with minimal performance penalty

Tags: node.js, webserver, persistent-storage

I'm running a node web server using express module and would like to include the following features in it:

- primarily, track every visitors source IP, time and unique or repeated visit by saving it to a JSON file.
- secondly, if someone is hitting my server more than 10 times in last 15 seconds looking for vulnerabilities (non-existent pages) then collect those attempts in a buffer (that holds 30 seconds worth of data) and once threshold is reached, start blocking that source IP for X number of hours.

I'm interested in finding out the fastest way to save this information with very minimal performance penalty.

My choice so far is to create a RAMDISK and save this info into a continuous file on that RAMDISK.

The info for Visitor info gets written to a database every few minutes.

The info for notorious visitors will be reset every 30 seconds so as to keep the lookup quick.

The question I have is - Is writing to RAMDISK the fastest way to retain information (so its not lost during a crash) or is there a better/faster way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: what is "RAMDISK"?

Comment: @Lloyd . RAMDISK is an area of RAM allotted and mounted as a regular Disk so we can create files and folders there. The purpose is primarily to provide persistence in the event of application crash, but of course if the device reboots that all data in RAMDISK is lost. My thought is that reading and writing to RAMDISK is faster than reading/writing to actual disk. Never did any tests so I don't know how fast it is for small frequent transactions.